# Is it alright to write a title like "some question about X anime series"?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I want to ask a question about some anime series which is divided to few similar questions.
So to make it more efficient, I thought to assemble all of them to the same question page.
I think it will be less contradicting one another if so.

Let's say for example:

- What are the differences (in general) between the light novel and the
  manga of the series X?
- Where is the season 2 ends up in the light novel and where in the
  manga?
- Is the manga reaches to the end of the light novel?

Comment: Please edit in an example. It's hard to say anything without.

Comment: @nhahtdh I have edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the questions are *very* closely related, to the point that it is not possible to answer one without answering the other, this makes things less efficient, not more. The reason is that often times an answerer may only know the answer to one of the questions. They then are either stuck writing an incomplete answer which only addresses one part of your question, or not answering at all. Either way is bad. With an incomplete answer, the chance that someone else will come around to answer the other parts drops even further. If they don't post anything, then it's a waste of an opportunity.

In addition, the title "Some questions about X" is really pretty terrible as a question title. There's no way anyone will find your question when searching on Google or other search engines. That means that there's relatively little chance your question will even get seen much. Some regular users here may see it, but unless your series is very mainstream, there's no guarantee that those users will know anything about it.

It's almost always best to stick to one question per question and write a descriptive title. Posting multiple questions (if they are otherwise good), even over a relatively short period of time, is perfectly fine. It's not like we're at risk of running out of questions. On the other hand, asking multiple questions in the same post will often be closed as "Too Broad".